# Using regex to extract tag names and values

Tags: php, regex

I want to be able to extract the tag names and values of queries.

Given the following query:

```
title:(Harry Potter) abc def author:'John' rating:5 jhi cost:"2.20" lmnop qrs
```

I want to be able to extract the following information:

```
title => Harry Potter
author => John
rating => 5
cost => 2.20
rest => abc def jhi lmnop qrs
```

Note that a tag value can be contained in an '..', "..." or (...). It dosent matter which.

This problem was solved using the following:

```
$query = "..."; // User input

while (preg_match(
    '@(?P<key>title|author|rating|cost):(?P<value>[^\'"(\s]+)@',
    $query,
    $matches
)) {
    echo $matches['key'] . " => " . $matches['value'];
    $query = trim(str_replace($matches[0], '', $query));
}

while (preg_match(
    '@(?P<key>title|author|rating|cost):[\'"(](?P<value>[^\'")]+)[\'")]@',
    $query,
    $matches
)) {
    echo $matches['key'] . " => " . $matches['value'];
    $query = trim(str_replace($matches[0], '', $query));
}
```

Now this is okay for many cases. However, there are quite a few corner cases:

1) For example consider:

```
title:(John's) abc
```

should go to:

```
title => John's
rest => abc
```

but instead goes to

```
title => (John'
rest => s) abc
```

2) Also consider:

```
title: (foo (: bar)
```

should go to:

```
title => foo (: bar
```

goes to:

```
rest => (foo (bar)
```

How can I do this? Is regex even the best way to go? How else can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE** Fixed a mistake on one of the expected outputs

Comment: How do you define your separators and your escape/special characters? When you say `title:(John's) abc` should go to `title => (John's) abc`, it makes me think that every characters between two tags are part of the tag. However, when you write `title: (foo (: bar)` should go to `title => foo (: bar`, suddenly parenthesis have to be removed, so parenthesis look to be some kind of delimiter/separator ... what's the rule ?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte Sorry my mistake. Fixed it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to parse everything exactly with one regex like you do because you don't have the same rule for all your pairs (key, value). Indeed, a close parenthesis, for instance, would be accepted in the middle of the tag *author* but not in the middle of *title*. A single quote mark would be accepted in the middle of *title* but not in the middle of *author*, etc. So, even if your rule works in most of the case, your second capture group cannot be properly defined.

One way to improve your solution would be to use different regular expression for each tags. You could then do something like this :

```
$str   = "title:(foo (: bar) abc def ".
         "author:'John' "             .
         "rating:5 jhi "              .
         "cost:\"2.20\""              .
         "lmnop qrs ";


$regex = array(
  "title"  => "/(?P<key>title):[[:space:]]*\((?P<value>[^\)]*)\)/"       ,
  "author" => "/(?P<key>author):[[:space:]]*'(?P<value>[^']*)'/"         ,
  "rating" => "/(?P<key>rating):[[:space:]]*(?P<value>[\d]+)/"           ,
  "cost"   => "/(?P<key>cost):[[:space:]]*\"(?P<value>[\d]+\.[\d]{2})\"/"
  );

foreach($regex as $k => $r)
{
  if(preg_match($r, $str, $matches))
  {
    echo $matches['key'] . " => " . $matches['value'] . "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Nothing found for " . $k . "\n";
  }
}
```

However, note that this solution is not bullet proof. For example, you'll have a problem if the title of a book contains the string *author: 'JOHN'*.

In my opinion, the best way to avoid such issue is to define a grammatical rule for your input string and to reject all the strings that doesn't mach you rule. Well, it also depends on your requirements and on your application I guess.

---

**Edit**

> Note that a tag value can be contained in an '..', "..." or (...). It dosent matter which

In that case, your problem is still that

```
[\'\"\(](?P<value>[^\'\"\)]+)[\'\"\)]
```

is incorrect. Instead, you want that each pairs of delimiters match. There's an option in subpattern for that (reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php))

```
(?|\'(?P<value>[^\']+)\'|\"(?P<value>[^\"]+)+\"|\((?P<value>[^\)]+)\))
```

If you use `\` as escape char, the code becomes

```
$str   = 'title:"foo \" bar" abc def '.
         'author:(Joh\)n) '           .
         'rating:\'5\\\'4\' jhi '     .
         'cost:"2.20"'                .
         'lmnop qrs ';

$regex = "/(?P<key>title|author|rating|cost):[[:space:]]*" . 
         "(?|" . 
             "\"(?P<value>(?:(?:\\\\\")|[^\"])+)\"" . "|" . // matches "..." 
             "\'(?P<value>(?:(?:\\\\\')|[^\'])+)\'" . "|" . // matches '...'
             "\((?P<value>(?:(?:\\\\\))|[^\)])+)\)" .       // matches (...)
         ")/"; // close (?|...


while(preg_match($regex, $str, $matches))
{
  echo $matches['key'] . " => " $matches['value'] . "\n";
  $str = str_replace($matches[0], '', $str);
}
```

Output

```
title => foo \" bar
author => Joh\)n
rating => 5\'4
cost => 2.20
```

Comment: The key values can be contained in a qoute or brackets. It dosent matter which or what the tag key is. I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes I may have an escape character "\", but I did not mention this in the question.

Comment: If you don't need it `(?:(?:\\\\\")|[^\"])` just becomes `[^\"]` and the same modification apply the the other delimiters

Comment: Yes I think using separate regex expressions in the way to go. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Shame you can't do it in one go.

Comment: @YahyaUddin I found a way to do it in one go using some option in subpatterns. I edited the post.

Comment: Wow amazing. I'll ask if I have any issues!